# WCF - (Custom) binary serialisation

Tags: wcf, networking, serialization, binary, datacontract

I want to be able to query my database over the web, and I am wanting to use a WCF service to handle the requests and results. The problem is that due to the amount of data that can potentially be returned from these queries, I'm worried about how these results will be serialised over the network. For example, I can imagine the XML serialisation looking like:

```
<Results>
    <Person Name="Adam" DateOfBirth="01/02/1985" />
    <Person Name="Bob" DateOfBirth="04/07/1986" />
</Results>
```

And the binary serialisation containing types names and other (unnecessary) metadata. Perhaps even the type name for each element in a collection? o_o

Ideally, I'd like to perform the serialisation of certain 'DataContract'-s myself so I can make it super-compact. Does anyone know if this is possible, or of any articles which explain how to do custom serialisation with WCF?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to highlight lines of code, SQL or XML and use the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar when you enter the question to format those nicely, as code, with syntax highlighting

Answer (score 4):

WCF support a binary serialization format out of the box - it's used by default in the `netTcpBinding`. I would recommend to try and use that for your tests first - only if that doesn't work and doesn't compress enough, and you're confident you can outsmart and outprogram the entire WCF team, go and roll your own custom binary serialization format.

Check out some excellent resources:

- [Service Station: Serialization in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx)
- [Comparing Text and Binary Serialization in WCF](http://winterdom.com/2009/07/comparing-text-and-binary-serialization-in-wcf)
- [Comparing WCF Binary Encoding to .NET Serialization](http://rickgaribay.net/archive/2008/09/19/comparing-wcf-binary-encoding-to-.net-serialization.aspx)
- [Silverlight 2: Doing Custom Binary Serialization](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/03c16f90-6745-44c6-8d83-f768d09949de/silverlight-2-beta-2-doi.aspx)

With the composability of WCF bindings, you could easily also create a e.g. binary HTTP binding.

The main issue here will be: if you do something like this, both ends of the communication channel must agree on how things are done, e.g. you cannot expect a simple browser to be able to connect and understand your custom binary encoding anymore - you need to be able to control the client and the server side of the wire.

Comment: Regarding the phrase "outsmart and outprogram the entire WCF team": this is irrelevant. A custom binary serialization and encoding can always outperform a generic one, simply by taking advantage of knowledge about the objects serialized. There is no need to "outsmart" anyone.